# How to compile `linux-tools` (containing `perf` binary) from vanilla kernel sources?

Tags: apt, kernel, performance, deb, git

I can build working kernel packages (`kernel-image` and `kernel-headers`) from vanilla kernel git sources (plus any random patches I like) following instructions at http://veithen.github.io/2013/12/19/ubuntu-vanilla-kernel.html (most important parts copied below in case the referenced page goes away):

1. Have enough unused disk space (15-20 GB)
2. (once) `sudo apt-get install kernel-package git libssl-dev`
3. `git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git`
4. `cd linux`
5. (optional) modify the source as needed, apply patches, add remotes etc.
6. `cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config`
7. `yes "" | make oldconfig` or `make olddefconfig` unless you want to build an ancient kernel
8. `fakeroot make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-my-so-and-so-patches kernel-image kernel-headers -j $(nproc)` or maybe `make-kpkg --root=fakeroot --initrd --append-to-version=-my-so-and-so-patches kernel-image kernel-headers -j $(nproc)` (I'm not sure if there's a difference but I've used the former but found references suggesting the latter.)

However, `make-kpkg` does not know how to build package `linux-tools` which contains (among other things) the command `perf` which I really would like to use. I know that I could build `linux-tools` using Ubuntu source code (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) but **is it possible to create package `linux-tools` from vanilla source?**

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/362758/20336